# i get an error saying a function is undifined when i acces it in a different file

Tags: python, tkinter

im working on a python module for creating windows, and im working on a function to create text on the canvas. When i call the function in the user file:

```
#User file
from module import *

create_window()
newtext(text="hello", x="100", y="100")
newtext(text="world", x="200", y="200")
```

i get 2 times the same error:
Undefined variable "newtext"

this is the part of the module file its about:

```
#module file
def newtext(text, x, y, color="black", font="'Helvetica', 15"):
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text = text, font = (font), fill=color)
```

now the wrierd part about it is that if i do it like this:

```
#module file
def newtext(text, x, y, color="black", font="'Helvetica', 15"):
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text = text, font = (font), fill=color)

newtext(text="hello", x="100", y="100")
newtext(text="world", x="200", y="200")
```

```
#user file
create_window()
```

it works, does anybody know what im doing wrong?

incase you need to know: the files are in the same file
and **the function newtext is in the function create_window**<-- i think this might be the problem

**The full module code**:

```
def create_window(h="500", w="800", bg="white", title="winpy window", icon="winpylogo.ico"):
    global winpy
    winpy = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(winpy, height=h, width=w, bg=bg)
    canvas.pack()
    winpy.title(title)
    winpy.iconbitmap(icon)
    def newtext(text, x, y, color="black", font="'Helvetica', 15"):
        canvas.create_text(x, y, text = text, font = (font), fill=color)

    print("window created succesfully")
    winpy.mainloop()
```

Comment: Including the whole code might be ideal here or an example that we can run might be better

Comment: Okay, i will add that.

Comment: I don't get it, do you answer yourself? Because if the function declared inside other function, just call it like that obviously will not work.

Comment: @YossiLevi Yea i know but how do i make it work

Comment: try adding `return newtext`, not sure, but give it a try and include an example where your calling the nested function too

Comment: Where should i add that?

Comment: At the end of the function `create_window()` before `mainloop()`, give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define a function within a function. This does not work.
Consider creating a **class** *create_window*, then instantiate it, then use its **function** *newtext*.

Try something like this:

module.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
winpy = tk.Tk()

class create_window:
    def __init__(self, h=500, w=800, bg="white", title="winpy window", icon="winpylogo.ico"):
      self.canvas = tk.Canvas(winpy, height=h, width=w)
      self.canvas.pack()
      winpy.title(title)
      #winpy.iconbitmap(icon)
      print("window created succesfully")
    def newtext(self, text, x, y, color="black", font="'Helvetica', 15"):
        self.canvas.create_text(x, y, text = text, font = (font), fill=color)
```

user file:

```
#User file
from module import *

w=create_window()
w.newtext(text="world", x="200", y="200")
winpy.mainloop()
```